# What is the best way to fetch frequently changing data from the web?

Tags: python

I have to download a text file every 20 seconds and process it as a string

```
s=urlopen(url).read()
```

This works but I've read that it's not very efficient.

How would you do it?

Comment: Is performance a problem? Have you profiled yet? Where did you read that this was inefficient?

Comment: it's only inefficient because of caching of data previously requested. If you know the data is changing every 20 seconds, you have to hit the server.

Comment: only if the data isn't changing. If it changes roughly every 20 seconds, then you can read every 20 seconds. Also, I doubt that this would be an issue if it's every 20s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to save bandwidth would be to specify `If-Modified-Since` as part of your request, with the timestamp of the data that you already have. This way, if the data hasn't changed, you'd get a `304 Not Modified` response back.

"Dive into Python" seems to have [an example of doing just that](http://diveintopython.net/http_web_services/etags.html).

Comment: @Da9: It does, provided the PHP script handles the `If-Modified-Since` header (it has to be done by the script since nobody else can possibly know whether the dynamic page produced by the script will have changed). If the script doesn't, then the entire page will get re-send; this is exactly what's already happening with your current code.